# How many 3digit numbers can be written with $2,4,4,6,6$

Tags: combinatorics

How many 3digit numbers can be written with $2,4,4,6,6$ ?

I tried $\frac{5.4.3}{2!.2!} = 15$ but it's wrong.

when I solved the question "how many 3digit numbers can be written with $1,1,2$"
the solution $\frac{3.2.1}{2!}$ was correct but why this way doesn't work for above question?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

$$ 3! + 2 \times 3 + 2 \times 3 = 18 $$

The first $3!$ stands for the number of permutations with all of $2,4,6$.

The second term $2 \times 3$ means choosing among $4,6$, say $4$, $(^2C_1)$ to have $2$ of that digit permuted with $2$ $(^3C_1)$, i.e. $244$, $424$, etc.

The third term $2 \times 3$ means choosing among $4,6$, say $4$, $(^2C_1)$ to have $2$ of that digit permuted with the other digit, $6$, $(^3C_1)$, i.e. $644$, $464$, etc.

Your answer is wrong because in the denominator $2 \times 2$ means "regarding the two $4$'s are the same" and "regarding the two $6$'s are the same", but they may not appear, say in the first case above. Therefore case-splitting is needed. It is not the same for the case "$1,1,2$" since the two $1$'s must appear.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, You ask yourself in this way :

$1)$ How many choices do you have for the first digit? $(3)$

$2)$ How many choices do you have for the second digit? $(3)$

$3)$ How many choices do you have for the third digit? $(3)$

Then you should know how to do it already. My answer is provided that the digits can be repeated (which you did not specify clearly whether or not can repeat)

---

For the case of non-repeating , then you should do it this way:
break into three cases:

$1)$ first digit is $2$

$2)$ first digit is $4$

$3)$ first digit is $6$ and then use similar method above to solve it

Comment: Choosing $2$ for the first digit, there are only 2 choices for the next digit, since we only have a single $2$.